# Maximum filename length while uploading using Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I just want to know that is there any maximum filename length while uploading file through Blob storage.when i am uploading my file then they are uploading successfully but when i am trying to download that file they are showing in different formats.means they are downloading as zip folder which contains such files which i never uploaded.Can anybody tell what can be the issue.

Comment: If you still need help with this issue try posting your code.

Comment: I am not able to understand still whenever i am uploading office2007 document/excel or ppt I am getting zip folder while downloading them .what is the reason for that?